# CSS - 100% height / width issue

Tags: html, css

I need your help with:

1. `html, body` and `#content` have a height of 100% && `#toolbar` have a height of 50px and he is static => I need to calculate the height of `#content` to fill the content without scroll bar
2. `#content > .a` must have a width of 300px and `#content > .b` must calculate the width to fill the content

**jsfiddle.net**:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/4uesapnt/2/
2. https://jsfiddle.net/4uesapnt/2/embedded/result/

[image]

Comment: You should use javascript for that. The logic is simple: 1st problem -> content.height = window.height - toolbar.height, similar thing for the second,  (toolbar_width - total_A_buttons_width) / number_of_B_buttons = width of a single button

Comment: But why are you trying to make this layout so "rigid"? I don't think that there are any solutions via css. Maybe you can try to solve your problem using the percentages

Comment: I don't see that piece of code in the example that you are providing there but i think that it is caused by the different margin or padding or border (there are some pixels that you have to take into account), try to use outerHeight http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/ that for your case is more precise

Comment: It was border... :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use the CSS3 `calc()` function ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) and viewport units (`vh`, `vw`) ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)) for this.

```
#content {
    height: calc(100vh-50px); /* substract #toolbar height from the entire page's height*/
}
```

2) Once again, you can use viewport units and the `calc()` function:

```
#content > .a {
    width: 300px;
}

#content > .b {
    width: calc(100vw-300px); /* substract #content .a's width from the entire page's width */
}
```

Here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hL7nxs6v/1/

Please note that if you resize the window to be less in width than `300px` + some reasonable width for `.b`, the layout might break if there aren't any appropriate `min-width`s assigned.

Browser support for [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), [calc function](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) via [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/).

Comment: It really works... where I can read about this new CSS features?

Comment: @MarekKobida Sorry, I had accidentally removed the links to the Mozilla Developer Network documentation. I have edited my answer, please try the links with the text 'docs'. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) is a great resource for reading up on all kinds of web technologies.

Comment: Please note that `CSS3` will be a perfect solution for you only if the old browsers are not your concern.

Comment: @hina10531 in 2015, only a small part of the world is using these _old_ browsers. Furthermore, developers and designers refusing to support browsers like IE8 only accelerates the switching process to modern browsers. For those old, stubborn users, you can use something like [Browser-Update](https://browser-update.org/) to tell them to update. Or they can just use broken sites. Their choice. As I stated in the post, browser support can be checked on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me in Chrome. I've never used `flex` before so I don't really know what the support is like:

https://jsfiddle.net/eeesrkjr/

I gave the `#content` a top padding to leave space for the header, and because of `box-sizing:border-box;` it doesn't force it over the 100% height. Then then header is absolutely positioned in that 50px space. I experimented briefly with getting the header inside `#content` so as not to have to absolutely position, but `flex` was doing weird things. Perhaps you could try that route if you have a better understanding of how those things interact.

HTML:

```
<div id="toolbar" class="flex aic jcsb">
    <div class="a">A</div>

    <div class="b">B</div>

    <div class="c flex aic jcsb">
        <div class="b">C</div>
        <div class="c">D</div>
        <div class="d">E</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="flex">
    <div class="a">A</div>

    <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #111;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    font-weight: 300;
}

#toolbar {
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    color: #bbb;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}

#toolbar > .c > div {
    margin: 0 12.5px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex.aic {
    align-items: center;
}

.flex.jcsb {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex.fdc {
    flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:50px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#content > .a {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}

#content > .b {
    background: blue;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 300px;` to `#content > .a` and you're golden.

Comment: @PatrickAllen Why is the `min-width` needed over the `width`?

Comment: If you inspect the #content div, you will see that it is only ~250px. This is because flex-box doesn't respect width.